# Label ASP not being set

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a label that is dynamically generated via a repeater, rollNo is a label that's a part of the itemTemplate. When I check the value of l, it goes in the if block but l.Text is still empty. check.Text only returns "d". Why?

```
        Label l = (Label)item.FindControl("rollNo");
        TextBox t = (TextBox)item.FindControl("quiz1");
        if (l != null)
        {
            string a = l.Text;
            check.Text = "d"+a;
        }
```

Comment: Oh and this rollNo label is a data.Eval parameter. I load data into repeater when I load the page.

Comment: Can you post the Repeater markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample isn't complete as it has no **rollNo** in it, but I can tell you something...
You are using repeater and with that using template...The id you use inside the template is never will be the run-time id of any of your controls! Think about it! Let say you assigned **rollNo** to one of the elements in the template and you have 10 rows to pass to the repeater. Are you expecting to have 10 controls with the the same id of **rollNo**?! I hope not! 
For that reason FindControl will return nothing while using on id inside a template...
You have to rethink what do you want or use a different approach to find the controls (loop)...

Comment: Yes got it, resolved it using OnItemCommand in Repeater. Code posted as an answer below.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Repeater Markup:**

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <tr onclick="rowReturn(this)">
             <td><asp:Label CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="rollNo"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sid") %></asp:Label></td>
             <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="quiz1" required></asp:TextBox></td>
             <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="quiz2" required></asp:TextBox></td>
             <td><asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm form-control" ID="add" CommandName="add" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sid") %>' /></td>
         </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
TextBox t1;
TextBox t2;
string rollNumber, T1, T2;
if (e.CommandName == "add")
{
    // get CommandArgument you have selected on the button
    string roll = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    rollNumber = roll;
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        t1 = (TextBox)item.FindControl("quiz1");
        t2 = (TextBox)item.FindControl("quiz2");
        T1 = t1.Text;
        T2 = t2.Text;
        //...DB code or any other code
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an asp:Repeater closing tag, wasn't getting embedded to text while writing the answer.
Hope anyone who reads this, gets it

Comment: Oh forgot it, this code behind snippet is inside the OnItemCommand function of Repeater